# API endpoint accepting changeable set of data

Tags: php, rest, api

One endpoint of my API must have a changeable data set depending on the context (some option, let's say a domain). How (apart from API documentation, of course) can we inform frontend that we are expecting such a data set? It comes to my mind to write an endpoint returning the fields that I expect in response (more specifically - the entire form with particular types of inputs, their placeholders, default values, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

The potential self-describing API you are looking for is [OPTIONS](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.7) HTTP request.

> The OPTIONS method requests information about the communication
> options available for the target resource, at either the origin
> server or an intervening intermediary.  This method allows a client
> to determine the options and/or requirements associated with a
> resource, or the capabilities of a server, without implying a
> resource action.

http://zacstewart.com/2012/04/14/http-options-method.html

For different possible datasets you can use custom `Content-Type` header like: `Content-type: application/vnd+some.payload+json`.

The good example of using those types is GitHub API: https://developer.github.com/v3/media/

Answer (score -1):

Return Http 400 Bad Request with JSON response containing URL to JSON Schema to which payload should comply.
Separate endpoint returning JSON Schema is also an option.

I don't know your case, but I dislike a idea of "changeable set of data". Maybe you can consider redesigning your API or wrapping your data sets into kind of container, so all of them can be described by single JSON Schema? (like in sample below)

```
{
            "oneOf": [
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": [ "domain", "content" ],
                    "properties": {
                        "domain":{"type": "string", "enum": ["domain1"]},
                        "content": {"type": "string"}
                    }
                },
                {
                    "type": "object",
                    "required": [ "domain", "content" ],
                    "properties": {
                        "domain":{"type": "string", "enum": ["domain2"]},
                        "content": {"type": "number"}
                    }
                }
            ]
}
```

depending on "domain" value, content can be either string or number